# Why GPU is not showing in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

My laptop computer is Dell xps 15 this has Intel and Nvidia GPUs. When I check by dxdiag it shows only Intel GPU.

[image: Direct]

When I go to the device manager it shows both GPUs.

[image: GPU]

Now when I type the following code I got **nothing** in Spider console.

Code 1:

```
Import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

Code 2:

```
Import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```

Code 3:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

def get_available_gpus():
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    return [x.name for x in local_device_protos if x.device_type == 'GPU']
```

What is the problem? How to solve this error? Do I need to enable or active something?

Comment: Thank you my CUDA compute compatibility is 2.1 so tensorflow request 3.5 or higher. That is the problem.

Comment: So what was the resolution? 
Which version of CUDA, tensorflow-gpu and keras did you end up using?